# Is there a Starcluster equivalent for Google Compute Engine (GCE) yet?

Tags: grid, sungridengine, google-compute-engine, starcluster, embarrassingly-parallel

Does anyone know if there is a Starcluster equivalent for GCE?  I have been quite happy using Starcluster with EC2 for embarrisingly parallel jobs. Now I want to try out GCE.  I would be happy to contribute to whatever projects might be in the works, but I haven't found anything.

For now, I guess I will just manually install the software I need (namely Open Grid Engine) and generate a copy image. Not too hard, but thought I'd check here first.